# How to properly combine two camera view matrices?

Tags: java, matrix, libgdx

Basically, I have a 3D hexagonal tile map (think something like a simplified Civ 5 map). It is optimized to use a single large mesh to reduce draw calls and easily allow for some cool Civ 5 features (terrain continuity and uv texture bleeding).

I want to support wraparound maps in my game, and so was brainstorming ideas on how to best do this.

For example, if the main camera is approaching the far east of the map, then I can simply perform the translation to the far west by doing:

```
if(camera.x >= MAP_WIDTH)
    camera.translate(0, 0, y);
```

However, by doing this, there will be a brief timespan in which the player will see the "end" of the board before the translation. I want to eliminate this.

The first idea I had to solve this problem was to basically just modify the above code as follows:

```
if((camera.x + camera.viewportWidth >= MAP_WIDTH)
    camera.translate(0, 0, y);
```

However, this has the side effect of a "jump" during the translation that feels unnatural.

**My final solution, and the subject of the question:**

I have three cameras, my main camera, one to the far east, and one to the far west. I basically want to "combine" the matrices of these cameras to render the map outside of its actual bounds.

Basically, if the camera is a certain distance from the world bounds, I want to draw the scene from the other side of the world in the following location. So, for example, this is the pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
int MAP_WIDTH = 25;
float viewportSize = 10f;
float mainCamX = 24f;
float mainCamY = 15f;
Matrix4 cbnd = camera.combined;
if(camX >= MAP_WIDTH)
    camX = 0;
else if(camX < 0)
    camX = MAP_WIDTH - camX;
if(camX + viewportSize >= MAP_WIDTH)
    cbnd = combineMatrices(mainCam.combined, westCam.combined);
modelBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cbnd);
modelBatch.begin();
//Draw map model
//Draw unit models.
modelBatch.end();
modelBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mainCam.combined);
```

But I am unsure of how to appropriately combine matrices, and am new to the concept of matrices in general.

Can somebody give me a hand in combining these matrices?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by combining matrices. What you describe sounds to me like you want to occasionally when camera moves to the edge of the world to start overflowing the map into view by taking rows of cells from the other side.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You understand the problem, but it is complicated by the fact that, in order to reduce render calls, I combined all of my individual tiles into a single, large mesh. Eg, when you reach the edge you cant just perform the simple mathematical operation of getting the tiles from the other side of the map and drawing them because the map functions as a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds too complicated. Here is my idea:

- I.e. you can display 10x10 fields on screen
- you have map 100x100 fields
- just increase your map to 110x110 and in that extra space repeat your first (zero-est rows and columns)

that way you can scroll smoothly and when camera reaches i.e. most right position you have on map just return it to 0 X position. Same goes for vertical movement.

So, idea is to have double most left part of map in width of screen width and most top part of map in size of screen height at rigth/bottom of the map respectively.

Comment: I did this originally. The problem was, when the player zoomed out, the device would be overwhelmed by draw calls (eg, at least one call per tile, as the tiles each had their own 3D meshes). I solved this by combining the geometry of every tile on the map into one large mesh and rendering it as such. However, this approach made rendering tiles from the other side of the map at the offset complicated if not impossible.